# incompatible data type in conversion: from SQL type VARCHAR to java.lang.Long

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, hybris-data-hub

```
ERROR [hybrisHTTP15] [FlexibleSearch] Flexible search error occured...
Aug 16, 2022 5:37:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [DispatcherServlet] in context with path [/trainingstorefront] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.search.exceptions.FlexibleSearchException: SQL search error - enable the property 'flexible.search.exception.show.query.details' for more details] with root cause
org.hsqldb.HsqlException: incompatible data type in conversion: from SQL type VARCHAR to java.lang.Long, value: customer10
        at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
```

In my SAP Hybris flow, I'm hitting the url from the Controller. While the data is being retrieved from the DB, I am getting the above mentioned error.
P.S.: the customer name "customer10" is being loaded correctly but facing this issue. The code to retrieve data from DB is attached below:

```
@Override
    public List<NewCustomerModel> getCustomerNameFromID() {
        final StringBuilder query=new StringBuilder();
        query.append("SELECT {" + NewCustomerModel.NAME + "} FROM {" + NewCustomerModel._TYPECODE + "} WHERE { "+ NewCustomerModel.CUSTID + "}=1");
        final FlexibleSearchQuery flexQuery = new FlexibleSearchQuery(query);
        final SearchResult<NewCustomerModel> searchResult = flexibleSearchService.search(flexQuery);
        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(searchResult.getResult()))
        {
            return searchResult.getResult();
        }
        return Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
    }
```

Please let me know if there is any error in the query or is there any configuration issue?

Comment: It should be `Collections.emptyList();` Otherwise type-safeness is no longer checked by the compiler.

Comment: `CUSTID` is maybe a `VARCHAR` where that `1` is not?

Comment: in items.xml file, custid is a String variable. Can you tell me how can I make changes in the query?

Comment: `='1'` if 1 is indeed the desired CUSTID

Comment: After changing the qurery to:
"SELECT {" + NewCustomerModel.NAME + "} FROM {" + NewCustomerModel._TYPECODE + "} WHERE { "+ NewCustomerModel.CUSTID + "}='1000'"

still the output is:
incompatible data type in conversion: from SQL type VARCHAR to java.lang.Long, value: customer1 where custid is String and 1000 is indeed the custid which has the customer name as "customer1"

Comment: We are stuck. get the string from `query` and try that is some SQL tool like Toad or such. I assume `{`...`}` is that database's convention for a complex name = with special chars, or a reserved word. Try without them, Or it might be a conversion of a field like NAME being annotated as long i.o. String.